# Unable to download videos from YouTube using pytube in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0")
yt = yt.streams.first()
yt.download('Downloads')
```

I'm using pytube for downloading the videos from YouTube, but it's throwing the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/landchecks/download_video", line 2, in <module>
    yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0")
  File "E:\Python\landchecks\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.prefetch_init()
  File "E:\Python\landchecks\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 97, in prefetch_init
    self.init()
  File "E:\Python\landchecks\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 143, in init
    mixins.apply_descrambler(self.player_config_args, fmt)
  File "E:\Python\landchecks\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\mixins.py", line 96, in apply_descrambler
    for i in stream_data[key].split(',')
KeyError: 'url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'
```

Comment: https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/467

Comment: by installing pytube3 instead of pytube, the issue is resolved